# Check multiple extension in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone how can I check my multiple file extions in input button with javascript like file must be mp3,mp4

```
<p><input type="file" id="file" name="file" size="23"/></p><br />
        <p><input type="submit" value="Upload file" /></p>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        var selectedFile = $('#file').val();
        var matches = selectedFile.match(/\.(xlsx?)$/i);
        if (matches == null) {
            alert('please select an Excel file');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var validFilesTypes = ["mp3", "mp4"];
function Validate(path) 
{        
 var ext = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, path.length).toLowerCase();
 var isValidFile = false;
 for (var i = 0; i < validFilesTypes.length; i++) 
 {
   if (ext == validFilesTypes[i]) 
   {
     isValidFile = true;
     break;
   }
 }
 if (!isValidFile) 
   alert('Please select file of mp3 and mp4 extension only.');             

 return isValidFile;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a regex:

```
filename.match(/\.mp[34]$/i);
```

substr:

```
if (filename.substr(-4) === '.mp3' || filename.substr(-4) === '.mp4')
{
    //do stuff
}
```

or even `split`:

```
var parts = filename.split('.');
switch(parts[parts.length -1])
{
    case 'mp3':
    case 'mp4':
        //do stuff
    break:
    case 'txt':
        //etc...
}
//or even:
if (filename.split('.mp').length > 1){}
```

And `indexOf`, of course:

```
if (filename.indexOf('.mp') !== -1)
{
    //note, still need to check if it's mp>3< or mp>4<
}
```